# malloc void return char array somtimes not working (terry davis was right about C++);

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

why does this cause a break in VS, I assume its because the pointer __array_buffer seems to be dealloc after update_typeArray finishes round about the third call but not always.
I have no clue why. pleas help me
(this is not the entire file, but the rest is mostly commented out and has no affect)
this does not happen if I make update_typeArray a char * and __array_buffer = the return(return would be the pointer of __array_buffer passed in param).
I would do that but I was hoping for overloading. 何でなの。please someone help me.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <conio.h>

//winigga stuff
# define VT100_WinAPI \
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);\
DWORD dwMode = 0;\
GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);\
dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;\
SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
Increment before use if index is 0 from init, (Char)array must contain a single value, and will recive '/0'.
Size of array is calculated by overloads input type and index (with null terminater taken in to account).
*/
void update_typeArray(char * char_array, int index, char input)
{


    char * new_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string


    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i < index)
        {
            new_array[i] = char_array[i];
        }
        if (i == index)
        {
            new_array[i] = '\0';//'\000' cause string
        }
    }

    free(char_array);
    new_array[index - 1] = input;
    char_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i < index)
        {
            char_array[i] = new_array[i];
        }
        if (i == index)
        {
            char_array[i] = '\0';//'\000' cause string
        }
    }


    free(new_array);

}
/*
Increment before use if index is 0 from init, (Int)array must contain a single value.
Size of array is calculated by overloads input type and index.
*/
//Debug
/*
void update_typeArray(int * int_array, int index, int input)
{

    int * new_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(index));

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {

        new_array[i] = int_array[i];

    }

    free(int_array);
    new_array[index - 1] = input;
    int_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(index));

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {

        int_array[i] = new_array[i];

    }

    free(new_array);

}
*/

int main()
{

    VT100_WinAPI

    while (!(GetKeyState(0x1B) & 0x8000))
    {

        if (_kbhit()||true)
        {

            char * __array_buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); __array_buffer[0] = '\0';
            int index = 0;
            bool chbuff_cyc = true;
            int size;

            while (chbuff_cyc)
            {
                char j[] = "reta";

                char __char_buffer = j[index];//_getch();

                if (__char_buffer == '\0')
                {
                    chbuff_cyc = false;
                    size = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++index;
                    update_typeArray(__array_buffer, index, __char_buffer);

                }
            }

            if (size > 0)
            {
                bool * blist = (bool*)malloc(size);
                //-----------|searchCommand (Start)|------------




                if (size == StringSize("a"))
                {
                    compare_typeArray(__array_buffer,"a",size,blist);
                    if(checkem(blist,size,and))
                    {
                        _putch('a');
                    }
                }


                //-----------|searchCommand (End)|------------
                free(blist);    
            }

            free(__array_buffer);
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBZnB.jpg

Comment: FWIW you really aren't using C++.  You're basically using C in C++.

Comment: Note: The name "__array_buffer" is not a valid one for you to use. Names containing double underscore (and several others; like names using "leading underscore followed by capital letter" and names ending in "_t", and more) are *reserved for the implementation* and should *not* be used in user code.

Comment: `bool * blist = (bool*)malloc(size);` -- This seems incorrect.  `malloc` does not allocate the number of `bool` values -- it allocates the number of *bytes*.  Second, why not write C++ and use `std::vector<char>`, `std::vector<bool>`, `std::string`, or some combination of those?  What's all of this stuff with `malloc` about?

Comment: Seems like a perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @JesperJuhl C++ Standard makes `_t` suffix reserved for implementation?

Comment: @ NathanOliver  like i said, this is only the code I'm concerned with. i have classes that are not part of the problem. @Jesper Juhl no problem has arises as a result( proof of this is that the name change does not solve the problem)

Comment: `update_typeArray` does *nothing* to the caller's provided arguments on the caller side. I hope you understand that. Specifically, `char_array = ....` in that function means nothing to the caller, ultimately leaking memory and leaving the caller with a dangling pointer of what was originally passed in. `char_array` is passed-by-value pointer. Changing its value means nothing to the caller; only changing what it being pointed to is realized caller-side, and in this case, that change is destroying the buffer and leaving the caller hung out to dry. Any dereference of that pointer after is UB.

Comment: @DanielLangr IIRC the standard doesn't. POSIX does.

Comment: @Zeglovrk Why you don't want to use the standard containers?

Comment: Be really careful with names like `__array_buffer`. For more on that read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @Zeglovrk The absence of evidence of a problem (in this case "no problem so far") is not proof of correctness. Undefined behavior can do anything, including appearing to work as intended for now. It's unquestionably undefined behavior to have an identifier with two consecutive underscores in c++. Even if fixing it doesn't solve this specific problem, it doesn't mean that it's not *also* a necessary fix to your code. At the very least, when diagnosing a problem, all sources of undefined behavior must be eliminated before anyone can think rationally about the code in question.

Comment: What did Terry Davis say about c++ that is apparently right about?

Comment: @Zeglovrk - what François said.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Does it mean that I should not compile/run a C++ Standard compliant code with an identifier having `_t` suffix on POSIX-based system (e.g., Linux)? What is the problem? Undefined behavior?

Comment: @DanielLangr I don't know the details.

Comment: What will happen if you drive without a license? You probably won't get caught, but this obviously doesn't prove that driving without a license is OK. Especially in a language like C++, doing something wrong doesn't necessarily mean you will get an error.

Comment: @FeiXiang i understand, but once i change the name to arrayBuffer, the problem persists, so even if the __ is causing an error, it is not the current error Im concerned with. but I thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem to cause undefined behavior is

In `void update_typeArray(char * char_array, int index, char input)`
you free the memory pointed by the `__array_buffer` using  `char_array`.

```
 update_typeArray(__array_buffer, index, __char_buffer);

 free(char_array);
```

and you allocate the new memory to `char_array`

```
char_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string
```

but your `__array_buffer` will be still pointing to freed memory.

and you continue to use the `__array_buffer` in `main` after freeing

`compare_typeArray(__array_buffer,"a",size,blist);`

`free(__array_buffer)`

**To understand easily consider below pictures.**

```
 ----------------             -------
| __array_buffer |  -------> | memory| 
  ---------------             -------
```

after call `update_typeArray(__array_buffer, index, __char_buffer);`

```
     ----------------             -------
    | __array_buffer |  -------> | memory| 
      ---------------             -------
                                   ^
                                   |
                            ----------------
                           |    char_array |   
                             ---------------
```

after     `free(char_array);`

```
 ----------------             
| __array_buffer |  ------->   X 
  ---------------             
                               ^
                               |
                        ----------------
                       |   char_array   |   
                         ---------------
```

After `char_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string`

```
     ----------------             
    | __array_buffer |  ------->   X 
      ---------------             


  ----------------           -------
 |  char_array    | -----> | memory| 
   ---------------           -------
```

**Solution:**

If you want to `__array_buffer` to point to new memory you got use pointer to pointer as below.

`void update_typeArray(char ** char_array, int index, char input)`

and you call the update_type.

`update_typeArray(&__array_buffer, index, __char_buffer);`

your update_typeArray may look like below.

```
void update_typeArray(char **char_array, int index, char input)
{


    char * new_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string


    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i < index)
        {
            new_array[i] = (*char_array)[i];
        }
        if (i == index)
        {
            new_array[i] = '\0';//'\000' cause string
        }
    }

    free(*char_array);
    new_array[index - 1] = input;
    *char_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i < index)
        {
            (*char_array)[i] = new_array[i];
        }
        if (i == index)
        {
            (*char_array)[i] = '\0';//'\000' cause string
        }
    }


    free(new_array);

}
```

Comment: char_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(index + 1));//+1 cause string -- so does this malloc not work after free? because it works some times? how wold you do this?

Comment: No, `char_array` is local variable.

Comment: sounds grate but the new_array and input? must i add ptr operator to them too?

Comment: No need for new_array

Comment: How are you accessing `char_array` in `update_typeArray` function

Comment: via ptr now. but it made no difference.

Comment: What does `compare_typeArray` does?

Comment: how do i change the code in update_typeArray to make this work?

Comment: Don't free and allocate new  memory. Just remove those lines from update_typeArray

Comment: @Zeglovrk Sorry I mistook it, yes should update. for that you need to use pointer to pointer as i suggested in my answer.

Comment: That is what i dont understand, there is alot of  referance for this but the pointer to pointer specifically regarding this case is where it falls short, how to implement it i don't know, and i suspect i may have not done it right the first time. thank you for your help

Comment: i did something similar except i had used (*char_array) = malloc, and it didn't work, but this seems fine

Comment: thank you for your time and effort, and thanx for helping me achieve what i wanted, not what C++ can offer as an alternative, because if c++ is a super set of C then this is still applicable. 